# SQL Server : generate continuous number

Tags: sql-server

There is my table :

```
ID  code(varchar)
1   006
2   008
3   005
4   010
5   002
```

I have created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC pp
    @code VARCHAR(10),
    @new_code VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 1 @new_code = RIGHT(1000+code+1,3) 
    FROM tb AS a 
    WHERE [Code] >= @code
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb WHERE [Code]=RIGHT(1000+a.[Code]+1,3)) 
    ORDER BY RIGHT(1000+code+1,3)
END
```

When I call this stored procedure below the result is 011, it is correct:

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(3)

EXEC pp '009', @code OUTPUT

SELECT @code
```

When I call the stored procedure below, the result is 011 remain, so the result is wrong. It should be '004'.

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(3)

EXEC pp '003', @code OUTPUT

SELECT @code
```

How to correct this? TKS!

Comment: So you just want to find the next number? Why not just use your ID column? It looks like it's an identity, which means it'll already increment for you.

Comment: Why can't you just use a `INT IDENTITY` column and let SQL Server handle all the details of incrementing and making sure not to return any duplicates? Your code - even if it worked as such - wouldn't be concurrency-safe under load - multiple clients calling the stored procedure might get back the same "new" value ....

Comment: from what I can see, it's doing what you asked it to.  when you say 'WHERE [Code] >= @code', if you pass in 003, it will also act on 010, as 10 > 3

Comment: I don't get why you are expecting the new code to be `'004'`. Fot that to happen, just looking at your code, you would need the code `'003'` on your table, since the new code is adding one to some existing code, so, your result is just not gonna happen

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the fact that you are selecting top 1, and ordering by a field that is not a number, but is a varchar, when you are expecting the order by to behave like a number. Have you tried casting/converting the [Code] field to an int, and then ordering by that value?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your sproc,it looks like you just need to increment the @code parameter value by 1.
For that why are you doing all this calculation in sproc.Like you are selecting from tb and checking it for > somevalue and all.

if you want to only increment the value there are lot better easier ways.